# How not split a string to retrieve usernames but not ones that include invalid characters for a username

Tags: python

The code below is designed to get the usernames out of a string and then return a specific username based on its position in which it came in the string. The issue I'm having is that usernames should only contain numbers, letters (upper and lowercase) as well as the special characters - and _ the code does this for most cases, however, I need it to not acknowledge usernames that contain invalid characters during the username.

For example in the following message "Hey @Joe07 what is @false,username! are we meeting @Fred08?"

"Joe07" and "Fred08" should be retrieved as usernames but not @false,username! which is currently retrieved as "false"

Please ask me any questions if needed, I've tried to make the question as clean as i can but it may still be a bit off.

```
 import re
    class Solution:
        def get_username(self, message, position):
            split_msg = re.findall(r"^@[\w\-]+|[\.\,\ ]@[\w\-]+", message)
            try:
                return_str = re.sub('.*@', '', split_msg[position - 1])
            except:
                return_str = ""
            return return_str
```

Comment: try using python-usernames it works quite well for most of the part you can refer https://pypi.org/project/python-usernames/

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler way to go through this is:

```
text = "Hey @Joe07 what is @false,username! are we meeting @Fred08?"

splittxt = text.split(" ")
final = []
for i in splittxt:
    if i.find('@') != -1:
        final += [i]
    else:
        pass
```

For removing the extra special characters at the end you can write a simple line of code like you did above for identifying those characters.

**OUTPUT:**

```
['@Joe07', '@false,username!', '@Fred08?']
```

Comment: when using this i get the following error local variable 'final' referenced before assignment

Comment: apologies, add: final = [] before the for loop. Edited the main answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Seems you missed the strip(). Made it more pythonic

Code:

```
import re
def get_username(message, position):
    invalid_list = ['@false']
    split_msg = re.findall(r"^@[\w\-]+|[\.\,\ ]@[\w\-]+", message)
    return ''.join(g for g in split_msg if g.strip() not in invalid_list)

message = "Hey @Joe07 what is @false,username! are we meeting @Fred08?"            
print(get_username(message, 0))
```

Output:

```
@Joe07 @Fred08
```